# Removing item from array by value in JavaScript giving unpredictable results

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have this code for removing an item from an array by value in JS...

```
function remove_item(index){

    //log out selected array
    console.log('before >> ' + selected); //

    //log out item that has been requested to be removed
    console.log('removing >> ' + index);

    //remove item from array
    selected.splice( $.inArray(index,selected) ,1 );

    //log out selected array (should be without the item that was removed
    console.log('after >> ' + selected);

    //reload graph
    initialize();
}
```

This is what my array looks like...

```
selected = [9, 3, 6]
```

If I call `remove_item(3)` this is what gets logged out...

```
before >> 9,3,6
removing >> 3
after >> 9,3
```

After should be `9,6` not `9,3`

I'm totally stumped on this as it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't...

For example I just tried `remove_item(10)` and this worked...

```
before >> 1,2,10
removing >> 10
after >> 1,2
```

I'm sure it has something to do with this line:

```
selected.splice( $.inArray(index,selected) ,1 );
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's inconsistent, sometimes the parameter `index` is a string, and sometimes it's a number.

`$.inArray('3', arr)` will return `-1`.

`$.inArray(3, arr)` will return `1`.

```
[9, 3, 6].splice(-1, 1);  // removes last item from the array
```

See [splice's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

You can make sure it's always a number by doing this:

```
//remove item from array
selected.splice( $.inArray(Number(index),selected) ,1 );
```

... or ...

```
function remove_item(index){
  index = Number(index);
```

Comment: That resolved it - I ended up going down a slightly different route of reconstructing the array by looping through selected elements which seems to work much better. But this resolved the question. Accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works as intended.

I think you need to check your input array once more.
Is it really [9,3,6] or do you expect it to be that?

Comment: Yeah - logging it out is 9,3,6 100%